# Windows Live Mail event alarm

Tags: windows, windows-live-mail, windows-live

When I'm adding a new event to Windows Live Mail calendar, I don't see an "alarm" option.

I've read [somewhere](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windows.live.mail.desktop&tid=2530c24f-1cd1-43ff-b435-a28c73b7e015&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1) I need to be signed in to windows live for it to be available, but I'm using it just for another POP3 account.

How do I add an alarm to a new event?

Answer (score 1):

For now, sign up for a Windows Live Hotmail account. Then you can synchronize your alerts from Hotmail, Check out http://alerts.live.com/alerts/Default.aspx

> Thank-you for your interest in Windows Live Alerts. After much consideration we have decided to discontinue this service as part of the Windows Live offerings. Please sign up with Windows Live Alerts partners directly to  receive their newsletters or other content updates from them. Hotmail Calendar Alerts and reminders will continue to be managed by Windows Live Alerts for the time being.